# Making queries ManyToMany relationships

Tags: python, django, orm, models

I have a model named `AffectedSegment` which is used for store a corporal segments selection.

```
class AffectedSegment(models.Model):

    SEGMENTO_ESCAPULA = 'Escápula'
    SEGMENTO_HOMBRO = 'Hombro'
    SEGMENTO_CODO = 'Codo'
    SEGMENTO_ANTEBRAZO = 'Antebrazo'
    SEGMENTO_CARPO_MUNECA = 'Carpo/Muñeca'
    SEGMENTO_MANO = 'Mano'
    SEGMENT_CHOICES = (
        (SEGMENTO_ESCAPULA, u'Escápula'),
        (SEGMENTO_HOMBRO, u'Hombro'),
        (SEGMENTO_CODO, u'Codo'),
        (SEGMENTO_ANTEBRAZO, u'Antebrazo'),
        (SEGMENTO_CARPO_MUNECA, u'Carpo/Muñeca'),
        (SEGMENTO_MANO, u'Mano'),
    )

    affected_segment = models.CharField(
        max_length=12,
        choices=SEGMENT_CHOICES,
        verbose_name='Affected Segment'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.affected_segment
```

I have another model named  `Movement`, which is used for store a movement asociated or related with the previous corporal segment entered.

The idea is that one segment (`AffectedSegment` object) can have many movements, and one movement (`Movement` object) can be associated with one or many segments.

```
class Movement(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Movement type'
    )

    corporal_segment_associated = models.ManyToManyField(
        AffectedSegment,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Affected segment associated')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.type
```

This two models, I am referencing in this model

```
class RehabilitationSession(models.Model):

    affected_segment = models.ManyToManyField(
    AffectedSegment,
    verbose_name='Segmento afectado',
    #related_name='affectedsegment'
    )

    movement = models.ManyToManyField(
    Movement,  # Chained Model
    verbose_name='Movement',
    #related_name = 'movement'
)
```

My main doubt is How to can I lookup the content of `affected_segment` and    `movement` fields from `RehabilitationSession` model in my html templates.

I am trying pass these data of this way:

My views.py file

```
class RehabilitationSessionList(ListView):

    queryset = RehabilitationSession.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'rehabilitationsessions'
    template_name = 'finals_list.html'
```

And my finals_list.html template is:

```
<thead>
     <tr>
         <th>Affected Segment</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for a in rehabilitationsessions %}
<tr>   
    <td>{{ a.affected_segment }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

But when I access to my template via url, I get this:

[image]

Of course, the `RehabilitationSession` model does not have the `affected_segment` and `movement` fields explicitly declared, due to that the ManyToMany relationships create another intermediate models/tables of this way:

[image]

Via Django Shell, I can make the queries, navigating through of some of this tables/models

```
In [21]: RehabilitationSession.objects.filter(movement__type='Extensión')
Out[21]: <QuerySet [<RehabilitationSession: Andrea Vermaelen>]>

In [24]: RehabilitationSession.objects.filter(affected_segment__affected_segment='Codo
...: ')
Out[24]: <QuerySet [<RehabilitationSession: Andrea Vermaelen>]>
```

My question is how to can I make the queries in my views for the data appear in the templates,

Is possible that my models are not defined correctly? ...

I know that this should not be complex, but I would like receive some orientation about it for I retrieve the segments and movements of a person in a rehabilitation session.

Any orientation is welcome

**UPDATE**

In relation to the support that @Daniel-Roseman gave me, I extract also the movement field for attach it in the table.

```
{% for a in rehabilitationsessions %}
                {% for r in a.affected_segment.all %}
                    {% for l in a.movement.all %}
                         <tr>
                            <td>{{ a.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.patient.full_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.patient.user.birth_date }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.patient.user.age }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.patient.user.sex }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.upper_extremity }} <br/><br/> 
                                <strong>{{ a.pain_extremity }}</strong> </td> 
                            <td>{{ a.patient.dominant_superior_member }}</td>
                            <td>{{ r.get_affected_segment_display }}</td>

                            <td>{{ l }}</td>
                            <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><a href="{% url 'rehabilitationsessions:detail' a.id %}">Ver</a></button></td> 
                            <td><a href="{% url 'rehabilitationsessions:edit' a.id %}">Editar</a></td>

                          </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

And the movement it's showed. Works.
But when I edit the register for add some additional `movement` or additional `affected_segment`, the behavior is that is showed one new record of the this additional segment or movement, although it's not a new record in the database, is a new line of the same record ...

I think that this happened due to my three for loops ... 
It's something like this https://cldup.com/JRKuSRFPuD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said, `affected_segment` is a many-to-many field. That means it refers to *many* segments (and the name seems wrong, it should be plural). So you can't just output it, you need to iterate through it:

```
{% for a in rehabilitationsessions %}
   {% for r in a.affected_segment.all %}
       {{ r.get_affected_segment_display }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

See that since the field you're interested in on AffectedSegment, itself called `affected_segment`, has choices assigned, you can use `get_affected_segment_display` to display the readable value of the choice.